# Pyramids with java

Tags: java

i need help.
i try to make a pyramids that use two alphabet like this:

```
O
OO
OXO
OXXO
OXXXO
OXXXXO
OOOOOOO
```

well, because i still new with java
i'm stuck here

```
O
OX
OXX
OXXX
OXXXX
OXXXXX
OXXXXXX
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Xx {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Line of Pyramid :  ");
    x = Sc.nextInt();
    for (int y = 0; y <= x; y++) {
      System.out.print("O");
      for (int z = 1; z <= y; z++) {
        System.out.print("X");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `x` for the sample output here?

Comment: just check if z==y or y==x and print Os instead of Xs if either is true

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Xx {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("X :  ");
    x = Sc.nextInt();
    for (int y = 0; y <= x; y++) {
      System.out.print("O");
      for (int z = 1; z <= y; z++) {
         if(z==y||y==x)
          System.out.print("O");
         else
        System.out.print("X");

      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

you can identify the coloumn edge using z==y condition, and base coloumn should fill with 'O' , for check that y==x condition added in your code , will give your expected output

Answer (score 3):

I would start with a method to repeat a given character `n` times, something like

```
static String repeat(char ch, int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

then you can call it to build your pyramid. Something like

```
int x = Sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("O");
System.out.println("OO");
for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
    System.out.print("O");
    char ch = 'X';
    if (y == x) {
        ch = 'O';
    }
    System.out.print(repeat(ch, y));
    System.out.println("O");
}
```

Which (when I run it with `5`) generates (the requested),

```
O
OO
OXO
OXXO
OXXXO
OXXXXO
OOOOOOO
```

Comment: `OO` this is missing. second line of the pyramid.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x;
Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("X :  ");

x = Sc.nextInt();
for (int y = 0; y <= x; y++) 
{
    System.out.print("O");

    for (int z = 1; z <= y; z++) 
    {
        System.out.print("X");
        if(z == y)
            System.out.print("O");
    }
   System.out.println();
}
for(int i=0; i<= x+2; i++)
{
    System.out.print("O");
}
```

Output:

```
X :  5
O
OXO
OXXO
OXXXO
OXXXXO
OXXXXXO
OOOOOOOO
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, you're all awesome.

Comment: Instead of posting just the complete working solution, add some explanation like where OP went wrong and what you did to correct the errors. Answers with that content are a lot more valuable than code-only solutions. I'll gladly remove my downvote if you do.

Comment: second column should be  OO